# Email not receiving in Gmail

Tags: email, gmail, smarty, blacklist

There is a domain address and from this domain we send emails to users. The problem is that Gmail users don't receive any email, not even to spam (except a case, when an email arrived to spam). The users who have Yahoo email addresses receive emails into inbox. 
So I suppose that Gmail has put the domain in blacklist for some reason.

I tried to find out the cause of the problem. So I have tried [MXtoolbox](http://mxtoolbox.com/). Here is a screenshot:
[image: mxtoolbox screenshot]

So I saw that the domain is on 2 blacklists, and dmarc Missing or Invalid Record.

The error:

> AES128-SHA:128 CV=yes DN="/C=US/ST=California/L=Mountain View/O=Google
>   Inc/CN=mx.google.com": SMTP error from remote mail server after end of
>   data: 550-5.7.1 [Server Ip address] The IP address sending this
>   message does not have a\n550-5.7.1 P...

This is a generic template used for any emails:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 3.2 Final//EN">
<html>
    <head>
        <title><!--{$domain_name}--></title>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
    </head>
    <body marginheight="0" marginwidth="0" leftmargin="0" topmargin="0" bgcolor="#ffffff" style="background-color: #FFFFFF; text-align: center;">
        <div style="width: 701px;margin-left: auto;margin-right: auto;text-align:left;">
            <img style="margin:0;" src="<!--{$main_site_address}-->/images/email/<!--{$domain_name}-->.png" alt=""><div style="border-left: 2px solid #8fd5fe;border-right: 2px solid #8fd5fe;color:#044269;font:15px 'Times New Roman', Times, serif;">
                <div style="padding: 6px;">
                    <!--{$messageBody}-->
                </div>
            </div>
            <img src="<!--{$main_site_address}-->/images/email/bottom-img.gif" alt="" width="701" height="23">
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

$messageBody is filled with some custom templates. These are:

register:

```
 Thank you for registering at <a href="#" style="color:#119fd7"><!--{$domain_name}-->,</a>
 <br/>
 <br/>
 In order to finish the registration process, please click on the following link
 <br/>
 <a href="http://<!--{$domain_name}-->/register.php?a=activate&code=<!--{$code}-->"><!--{$domain_name}-->/activate.php</a> to validate your email.
 <br/>
 <br/>
 If you have questions please do not reply to this email, please send your questions to <!--{$help_email}-->
```

Forgot password:

```
Hello, <!--{$firstName}--> <!--{$lastName}-->. <br/>
<br/>
A new password request has been made for your account, if this is your request, use the following link to get a new password:
<br>
 <a href="<!--{$site_address}-->register.php?a=reset_password&code=<!--{$code}-->"><!--{$site_address}-->register.php?a=reset_password&code=<!--{$code}--></a><br/><br/>

 Thank you for using <a href="#" style="color:#119fd7;"><!--{$domain_name}--></a>, <br/><br/>
 If you ever need support or have comments for us contact our Customer Service Team <a href="#" style="color:#119fd7;"><!--{$domain_name}--></a>
```

New Password:

```
Hello <!--{$firstName}--> <!--{$lastName}-->, <br/>
<br/>
here is your new password: <!--{$password}-->
<br>

 Thank you for using <a href="#" style="color:#119fd7;"><!--{$domain_name}--></a>, <br/><br/>
 If you ever need support or have comments for us contact our Customer Service Team <a href="#" style="color:#119fd7;"><!--{$domain_name}--></a
```

Ad:

```
<!--{$label.ad_posted_email_text_part1}--> '<!--{$ad_title}-->' <!--{$label.ad_posted_email_text_part2}-->  <a href="<!--{$address}-->ad_view.php?id=<!--{$ad_id}-->"><!--{$address}-->ad_view.php?id=<!--{$ad_id}--></a>
```

What is common approach leading to the solution?

Comment: https://support.google.com/a/answer/3726730?hl=en  you could just look up the error code...

Comment: This isn't really a programming question, although it's no doubt a problem many programmers face; it's largely a systems / infrastructure problem. Blacklists are not generally interested in the content of e-mails, they are interested in the behaviour of hosts, and the "envelope" (headers and communication path) of the message. You need to click the "More Info" links on the report you screenshotted, and understand the terms used. You may also want to investigate using a 3rd-party mail provider rather than sending directly from your own SMTP server.

Answer (score 1):

Guluke,

You have to discover the reason why you are blacklisted and google uses it's own private blacklists. Even if you get removed from the public ones in your screenshot. It most likely won't solve your issue with gmail, which can be totally un-related. Also you would want to use a more complete: [Blacklist checker](https://www.unlocktheinbox.com/blacklist/bl/)

I think it checks over a 100 more than the one you are using. Next you'll want to test your email for everything, try using this [Mail Tester](https://www.unlocktheinbox.com/mail-tester/) it's the best one available.

You just have to peel back the different layers and start ruling things out one by one. I don't see anything wrong with the content you are sending out.